# YouTube Gdata APIU is no longer available, any alternative for this?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, gdata, android-youtube-api

Gdata API for YouTube feed is not working, from last some days.. so any alternative for to get feed from YouTube API..??

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL_yIBWagYVjyyqx_qPkbat5zufWZOyZEZ

Comment: This has been addressed in dozens of posts on this tag.  Search on SO or the YouTube v3 API documentation.

Answer (score -1):

1. Download YouTubePlyaer API https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/
2. Register your app on google developer console https://console.developers.google.com
3. Take an unique API Key and use that in your App.
4. use below code

   public class AboutUs extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.layout_about_us);

       YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
       youTubePlayerView.initialize(Constants.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);

       initViews();
   }

   private void initViews() {
       Button btnVisitMega = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_visit_megaforties);
       Button btnVisitSecurity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_visit_security_seals);

       btnVisitMega.setOnClickListener(this);
       btnVisitSecurity.setOnClickListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onInitializationFailure(Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
       Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   @Override
   public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
       /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
       player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
       player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

       /** Start buffering **/
       if (!wasRestored) {
           player.cueVideo(Constants.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID);
       }
   }

   private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener() {

       @Override
       public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onPaused() {
       }

       @Override
       public void onPlaying() {
       }

       @Override
       public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onStopped() {
       }
   };

   private PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onAdStarted() {
       }

       @Override
       public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
       }

       @Override
       public void onLoading() {
       }

       @Override
       public void onVideoEnded() {
       }

       @Override
       public void onVideoStarted() {
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: Vid, i m not looking to play the video.....read the question ... i need the feed of playlist... :(

Comment: Oh, Check out this link. https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters?csw=1

Comment: @Vid that's a link to the v2 API, it doesn't help the asker.